# Python: Saving a string to file without overwriting file's contents

Tags: python

I need to add my program's outputs to a saved file every time I run the program without overwriting the previous outputs.

This is how I'm writing to a file now:

```
lead.write(str(alldates))
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you should spend some time looking at the documentation for the most basic methods you might be using, such as [`open`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#open).

Comment: possible dup - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706499/how-do-you-append-to-file-in-python

Answer (score 2):

Here, you should `open` the file in `a`ppend mode:

```
append_text = str(alldates)
with open('my_file.txt', 'a') as lead:
    lead.write(append_text)
```

There are lots of specialised ways to `open` files for different purposes, and you can [read about them in the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open).

Answer (score 0):

You should open the file in append mode.